# How can I redirect social URL when user clicks on social icon by php?

Tags: php, facebook-social-plugins

html code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://simplesharebuttons.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

My problem is, I want to redirect the user when the user clicks on the facebook button to its facebook URL like $facebookid = facebook URL

Comment: I don't quie understand the question. When the user clicks the Facebook link, you want to open their profile? That's a share link?

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: how can i pass user url to <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $facbookid; ?>"?>

Comment: where is the issue? This line perfectly ok `<a href="facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $facbookid; ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have facebook url:

```
$facebookid = "https://web.facebook.com/abcxyz...";
```

just put it in html code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $facebookid?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

Comment: i try as you say but it's not redirect on user facebook page. for example if facebook user id is http//:xyz@gmail.com it's redirect on user gmail account not on facebook page i want facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but it render the facebook as a relative path and not a link

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<div class='col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center mb-5' data-aos='fade-up'>
                <img src='../images/person_4.jpg' alt='Image' class='img-fluid w-50 rounded-circle mb-4'>
                <h2 class='text-black font-weight-light mb-4'>" . $row['name'] . " " . $row['surname'] . "</h2>
                <p class='mb-4'>Years of experience:  " . $row['experience'] . "</p>";
                
                if ($row['man'] == 1)
                    echo "<i class='fa fa-male' aria-hidden='true'> </i>";
                if ($row['woman'] == 1)
                    echo "<i class='fa fa-female' aria-hidden='true'> </i>";
                
                echo "<a href=' " . $row['facebook'] . "' target='_blank'> <i class='fa fa-facebook' aria-hidden='true'> </i> </a>
                <a href=' " . $row['instagram'] . "' target='_blank'> <i class='fa fa-instagram' aria-hidden='true'> </i> </a>
                <a href=" . $row['email'] . " target='_blank'> <i class='fa fa-envelope-o'  aria-hidden='true'></i> </a>
                </div>";
            }
            echo "</div>";
```